# Can I set value from custom annotation to @PreAuthorize in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-el

I have created an annotation called @AllowAccessTo as follows,

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(@authorityService.getPrivilege(need to inject value form allowaccess annotation))")
public @interface AllowAccessTo {
    String value() default "";
}
```

In my Rest Controller, I have annotated that custom annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FooEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/students")
    @AllowAccessTo("GET_ALL_STUDENT")
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, I need to inject that "GET_ALL_STUDENT" value to

```
@authorityService.getPrivilege({{value from custom annotation}})
```

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(@authorityService.getPrivilege(value form AllowAccessTo annotation))")
```

Comment: hello, I have the same problem as you, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solve this.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("@securityHandler.check")
public @interface AllowAccessTo {
    String value() default "";
}
```

```
@Service("securityHandler")
@Slf4j
public class SecurityHandler {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;


    public boolean check() {
        try {
            log.debug("checking permission based on jwt");
            List < KseRoleDto > kseRoles = new ArrayList < > ();
            String accessCode = checkAllowAccess();
            // check permission with access code
            if (hasPermission) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("permission not matched and exception occurred", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String checkAllowAccess() {
        HandlerMethod attribute = (HandlerMethod) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE);
        GrantEndpoint methodAnnotation = attribute.getMethodAnnotation(GrantEndpoint.class);
        return methodAnnotation.value();
    }

}
```

Comment: public String checkAllowAccess() {
        HandlerMethod attribute = (HandlerMethod) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE);
        GrantEndpoint methodAnnotation = attribute.getMethodAnnotation(GrantEndpoint.class);
        return methodAnnotation.value();
    }